# 4 column-loop ordered alphabetically with entries grouped (and labeled) by their first letter

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, order, columns

I found some code for creating multi-column WordPress loops and I found some code for entries grouped by letter of the alphabet. But I can't quite get the code to work together...the order is a bit messed up.

EXAMPLE

http://52words.org/w/

I would appreciate some assistance.

```
<style>
.col { width:24%; float:left; margin-right:5px; }
</style>

<?php
$num_cols = 4; // set the number of columns here
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; // for pagination
$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'title',
  'order' => 'ASC', 
  'posts_per_page' => '199',
  'paged' => $paged,
  'post_type' => 'wiki'  
);
query_posts($args);
//end of query section
if (have_posts()) :
  for ( $i=1 ; $i <= $num_cols; $i++ ) :
    echo '<div id="col-'.$i.'" class="col">';
    $counter = $num_cols + 1 - $i;
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
      if( $counter%$num_cols == 0 ) : ?>

        <?php 
        $title=get_the_title(); 
        $initial=strtoupper(substr($title,0,1));
        if($initial!=$letter)
          {
          echo "<h3>$initial </h3><ul>";
          $letter=$initial;
          }
         { ?>

<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php _e( 'Permanent Link to', 'buddypress' ); ?> <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

<?php }   ?>

      <?php endif;
      $counter++;
    endwhile;
    rewind_posts();
    echo '</ul></div>'; //closes the column div
  endfor; ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, from what I can tell, you want four columns of relatively equal length on a page, with a title letter every time you move on to a new letter of the alphabet.

```
<?php
$num_cols = 4; // set the number of columns here
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; // for pagination
$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'title',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'posts_per_page' => '199',
  'paged' => $paged,
  'post_type' => 'wiki'
);
$wikis = new WP_Query($args);
//end of query section

if ($wikis->have_posts()) :
  // figure out where we need to break the columns
  // ceil() rounds up to a whole number
  $break_at = ceil( $wikis->post_count / $num_cols );
  // start with the first column
  $col_counter = 1;
  $post_counter = 1;
  // Set the title letter empty so that it's always output at the beginning of the cols
  $initial = '';
  ?>
  <div id="col-<?php echo $col_counter ?>" class="col">

  <?php while ($wikis->have_posts()) : $wikis->the_post();

    // Start a new column (but not the first one)
    if( $post_counter % $break_at == 0 && $post_counter > 1 ) :
      $col_counter++;
      ?>
      </ul></div>
      <div id="col-<?php echo $col_counter ?>" class="col"><ul>
    <?php endif;

    $title = get_the_title();
    $wiki_letter = strtoupper(substr($title,0,1));

    if( $initial != $wiki_letter) : ?>
      <?php if ( $post_counter > 1 ) : // close the previous ul ?>
        </ul>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <h3><?php echo $wiki_letter ?></h3>
      <ul>
      <?php $initial = $wiki_letter;
    endif; ?>

    <li>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php _e( 'Permanent Link to', 'buddypress' ); ?> <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php echo $title ?></a>
    </li>
    <?php $post_counter++; ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  </ul>
</div>

<?php wp_reset_postdata();
endif; ?>
```

This code does have a small bug where if a new letter of the alphabet starts at the same time as a new column, there's an empty `<ul>` tag at the beginning of the column.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The code now sorts entries properly. But the h3 and ul tags are now prefaced before every link/list item, instead of grouping bullet lists by their first letter.

Comment: I misspelled '$initial' as '$inital` inside the `if ($initial != $wiki_letter)` block. It should work if you correct the spelling mistake.